# How to remove /en/ in the default url - Prestashop

Tags: url-rewriting, prestashop

How to remove the /en/ url in the website

by default site showing as like above.

please check the following url

http://www.plrebooksstore.com

it goes to http://www.plrebooksstore.com/en/

Please help me out

Thulasi.

Comment: Using firebug, you'll find out that the http://www.plrebooksstore.com sends an HTTP 301 header. You should clarify your question because there are several ways that could lead to this behaviour, e.g. server-side PHP header() function or Apache RewriteRule directives. In other words, have you access to server config files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the /en/ url in the website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962453/how-to-remove-the-en-url-in-the-website)

Answer (score 1):

In the prestashop backend go to Tool>Languages and disable all the languages other then english.

Comment: That does not really help. I need two languages for instance.

Answer (score -1):

See my answer here: [How to remove the /en/ url in the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962453/how-to-remove-the-en-url-in-the-website/6198606#6198606)