# How to remove the /en/ url in the website

Tags: url, prestashop

How to remove the /en/ url in the website

by default site showing as like above.

please check the following url

http://www.plrebooksstore.com

it goes to http://www.plrebooksstore.com/en/

Please help me out

Honney.

Answer (score 2):

In prestashop, country code appears only if you have more than one language.
If en is your only option, disabling the rest will let your store without the code.

Comment: Hi Ovidiu, I tried your solution, which did work, but the category links still have the "en/" link to them so they could not be accessed. It seemed that the category links are excluded from the language removal...unless Im forgetting something.

Comment: Try to regenerate .htaccess file again and see if that's working.

Comment: You still see en/ because of the smarty cache. Remove all the files in tools/smarty/compile/ and eventually in your theme also (themes/yours/cache/*). And it shall work.

Comment: That is not helpful for me at all. I need two languages.

Comment: Well, it is obvious that if you actually use languages on your presta install you don't need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the topic discussed here if you need to use multiple languages and you want to remove the default language iso from URLs:

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/550132-how-to-remove-main-language-in-url/

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 languages activated. Just de-activate one language, rewrite the .htaccess file and the links will change

Answer (score -1):

after deactivate one language go to dashboard>>>Preferences>>SEO & URL>>>change disable apache multiviews to yes